# OneLogin session_via_api_token how to "keep signed in"

Tags: api, session, authentication, token, onelogin

I'm using the OneLogin API to log-in user via API, so I create session login token then use CORS post and all is working fine.

My question is, when I log-in via OneLogin (so using https://{{subdomain}}.onelogin.com) form I make available the option "keep me signed in" (the checkbox) which maintain the session after the browser was closed.

But when I log-in a user via API is that possible to keep the session active even after the browser was closed ? Actually the session is like I don't check the "keep-me signed-in" option when I use the API.

Thanks a lot if you could have an answer.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this functionality isn't available via this flow. Let me talk to development to see about enabling this.

If you're a customer, you could also try reaching out to support.